# valid mountain array leetcode problem to be solve in python language need help to review code

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UElb.png)

```
class Solution(object):
    def validMountainArray(self, arr):
        """
        :type arr: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        list=[]
        for i in arr:
            if i not in list:
                list.append(i)
        if len(list)==len(arr):
            maxi=max(arr)
            index=arr.index(maxi)
            if arr[:index]==arr[:index].sort() and arr[index:]==arr[index:].sort(reverse=True):
                return True
```

for the testcase [0,3,2,1]
expected True
output False
why? where is the problem lies?

Comment: I would also like to add that your logic feels to be off right from the start, in the example that you have provided the mountain array does have two instances of `2` and thus the `len(list)==len(arr)` in your code will not execute that code block

Comment: You'll also probably run into failing test cases with large inputs due to time limits. This code iterates over the input once to build `list` and iterate over `list` (n^2)/2 times (worst case) for the membership check, once to calculate the maximum, and then somewhere between 2*(n/2)*ln(n/2) and n*ln(n) times to sort. Usually sites like Leetcode have tests for time complexity. This can be solved with a single iteration over the input.

Comment: @MichaelRuth The maximum input length is only 10000, so O(n^2) will be fine unless the constant factor is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I'll begin by explaining some of the problems in your solution (most of them already stated in comments):

- You forbid duplicate values in the array, whereas they should be allowed (one on each side of the mountain).
- You confuse arr.sort() (which sorts the array inplace and returns None) with sorted(arr).
- A problem not mentioned: even when fixing the two main problems above, your method doesn't ensure the **strict** ordering of values (it was probably what you were trying to do with the duplicate forbidding).
- Finally (though it's not what makes your algorithm fail), don't call your variables `list` or `index`: shadowing Python names is dangerous.

And now, being a lover of the `itertools` module, here's a solution making use of it: I transform the array into a succession of signs (ie sign of the delta between a value and the next one), then deduplicate consecutive signs; the expected result for a valid mountain is thus [1, -1]:

```
from itertools import pairwise, groupby

class Solution(object):
    def validMountainArray(self, arr):
        def diff_sgn(pair):
            return 1 if pair[1] > pair[0] else -1 if pair[1] < pair[0] else 0
        return [flag for flag, _ in groupby(map(diff_sgn, pairwise(arr)))] == [1, -1]
```

Comment: `index` is a perfectly fine name, doesn't shadow anything.

Comment: Agreed, but I avoid using methods' names too.

Comment: Why? ..........